# Access Sandbox meta data from a different Org

Tags: oauth2, metadata

I want to access Metadata of a salesforce org (either developer or sandbox) from another salesforce org. I think I can use oAuth 2.0 to access it.

basically what expected here is the user to access meta data of Org B from Org A. So Org A is probably be a sandbox and Org B is would be another dev sandbox or Production. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes...using SOAP and Enterprise WSDL along with oAuth you can get all the metadata you want...Also possible by tooling API I guess but never went that route

Comment: Thanks @Eric, Anyplace to get a sample code to get things start?

Comment: There is a whole guid already. Google metadata API developer guide.